# Working with Javascript object and array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm working on a requirement to dynamically insert text depending on user office locations. Suppose we have an array of `people` (4 person) and `office locations` (20 locations - 5 per person). I'm not sure what's the best of creating a **mapping** between the person and locations. An example of the what I'm trying to achieve when user's visit the page:

- We query user's office from AD (this is an intranet so user's will log in using creds)
- Compare user's office location to the mapping we have for `people` and `office locations`
- Insert the person's name from `people` when user's office matches one of the `office locations`

I don't have an issue with the first bullet point but not sure what's the best way of going about the other two, any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Hope I explained the problem well.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please create a more meaningful title that describes your actual question.

Comment: You can define an object with two properties: location and userID. THen you can push this object into an array.

Comment: Thanks Phong Vo! I did exactly this, the only addition I made was to use an array for userId property since there were multiple office locations for each person.